# Download uploaded files paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, download, paperclip

I have a problem when using paperclip.
I can see the files uploaded but now i want to have a download link to download the "pdf file" when clicking on it.

I see this example:

```
<%= link_to "Download", model.whatever.url(:original, false) %>
```

But I can't figure out how to implement this with my own views and models.

Hope someone can help me.

EDIT:

here is my model:

```
class Contractgegeven < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :pdf

    attr_accessible :bedrijfsonderdeel, :bestemd_voor, :betalingsgegevens, :betreft, :contractbeheerder, :contractduur, :einddatum, :ingangsdatum, :opzegtermijn, :soort_contract, :pdf
    end
```

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: Didi you try `Contractgegeven.last.pdf.url(:original)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your model is `Image`, and you have :

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :picture
```

Then you should write:

```
Image.last.picture.url(:original, false)
```

not `Image.last.url(:original, false)`

Comment: i have my model posted above, my model has a form with input fields for contracts and now i want to add the pdf of the contract to that form and i would like to download that uploaded pdf but thanks i will see of it works.

Comment: Thanks it worked as it should, but now it opens in the browser and does not download it. what's the problem?

Comment: Glad it worked. To make it download instead of opening in the browser, I guess you'll have to send the file from the controller using [`send_file(path, options = {})`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file). But that's another story ;-)

Comment: i just uploaded a word document and this is downloading like it should :D thanks for your help!

Comment: when i have to download pdf's i will ask here again ok :)? it's not necessary at the moment :)

Comment: I used last as an example. You should do something like `Image.find(params[:id]).pdf.url(:original, false)`